# Locked folder with obscure app from SourceForge - now I cannot unlock the folder

Tags: windows

I locked a folder containing some important files with an obscure application from SourceForge called [Folder Lock Pro](https://sourceforge.net/projects/folderlockerpro/). When the enter password dialog came up to lock the folder I changed my mind, and as there was no close icon (x) I merely clicked OK. The application locked the folder anyway and when I tried to unlock it, no password dialog came up.

I had the folder open in a window when I locked it, so I was able to bring up the property sheets of the various files in the folder. They were all 0 bytes in length. However, when I checked the property page of the locked folder itself, the size seemed to be the same as before I locked it - 10 files 648 KB in total, so I guess they still exist in some form.

On further testing with non-critical files (something I probably should have done originally) there is an extra file in the locked folder, created by the program. I used the first method of encryption. The author is clearly not available (the last post is five years ago) and I'm not hugely tech savvy, so how could I fix this problem?

My OS is Windows 10 Home.

Comment: I have successfully regained access to the folder with an app called "Lockhunter" which involved renaming the folder. All files are intact. Thank ****!

Comment: Any time you read "99% Hacker Proof Technology" or anything along those lines, just run.

Comment: _"The author is clearly not available (last post 5 yrs ago)"_ Bit of a reach there. Did you try?

Comment: @Voo _"99% Hacker Proof Technology"_ reminds me of [this xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1161/).

Comment: It's also not a sign of quality software that they misspelled the word "alpha" in the window title.

Comment: I guess you should be thankful that the software was just garbage rather than a scam. This could easily have turned into "I voluntarily installed ransomware and told it which folder was most important to me".

Comment: "I locked a folder containing some important files with an obscure application from Sourceforge [...]" <-- **Please** read what you're trying to get into, instead of just using some random software you found on a "random" website. A software you can try is Veracrypt.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: Sourceforge is not 'random' website. Many years is good repositary bazillion of the open source projects.

Comment: If you want a simple encryption, using the built in Windows BitLocker is all you'll ever need. See https://security.stackexchange.com/q/40441/207915 for example. The only concerns brought forward so far are that it is a MS product and may contain a backdoor. Though no security expert has found anything so far. So as of right now if you trust MS to run your OS, then you might as well trust its encryption.

Comment: @user2120666 I said "random", not random. I know Sourceforge isn't a random website. I gave it as a general advice. Imagine if you found "Secure File Encrypter (free)" on `fileencrypter.xyz`. As a regular user, you wouldn't know how to check if it is a malicious software or not.

Comment: @user2120666 Once upon a time, SourceForge was a good source of open source software, but those days are long gone. If a project's only hosting is on SourceForge, I would immediately assume that it is at best abandoned, and quite possibly hijacked to inject extra software into the installer. For a while SourceForge themselves were modifying installers to inject adware; I think they promised to stop, but they've never regained my trust.

Comment: @Voo I remember years ago I saw an article claiming that quantum physics encryption will be unbreakable. I mocked the article about it and a week later their thought was disproved. I think they might have - to their credit - written about it too. Though I prefer the term 'cracked' it's still a funny thing. It's also scary how naïve people can be. Oh well. That's the way humans are, hey? But yes you're right. As to the OP: You should write your own answer on what you did. I don't know about superuser SE but at least in other parts they suggest it and even marking it as the correct answer.

Comment: Oh and to the OP: **Please** start doing **regular backups**. Seriously. And also please know that a backup has to **remain secure**: If the backup volume is always accessible (as in writable) then it's not secure (or as secure as it should be). Off-site backups are also a very good idea but what would have happened if you lost something priceless over something like this? But this applies to everyone. I'm happy for you that you got your data back but **please learn from this**. For your own sake.

Answer (score 98):

[image: (Screenshot of the 'Folder Locker's main window)]

Despite the program claiming to use an "Encryption Library", there is no encryption in this software at all. It simply renames the folder to one of:

- Mode 1: `Example folder.{2559a1f2-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}`
- Mode 2: `Example folder.{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}`
- Mode 3: `Example folder.{2559a1f1-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}`

The folder and its contents remain fully accessible to software (e.g. through PowerShell or Command Prompt); the special name *only* tells Windows Explorer to show it as a special-purpose item and not a regular folder.

(For example, the 2nd GUID is the "Recycle Bin" CLSID. You might have heard of the same thing back in 2010, when a so-called "GodMode control panel" GUID was discovered in Windows 7.)

So the easiest recovery procedure would be to open Cmd and use `ren` to rename the folder back. The same could also be done via Total Commander, WinRAR, or just about any other third-party file management app you have at hand.

In all three modes, the files inside are completely untouched. (Except for the new file `p.xml` which contains your password – not only does the program fail to protect anything, it *also* stores your password in plain sight.)

Comment: Haha... wow, nice

Comment: Ah, you beat me to posting a review on SF about this fraud, I see

Comment: They even came up with fancy encryption library names, nice. :D

Comment: Good rule of thumb is to never use encryption software where the algorithms are named after the program's own author. If it uses algorithms named after _other_ people, it's probably ok.

Comment: Security through obscurity, and storing the password in plaintext. This is a terrible piece of software.

Comment: To be fair, it's not the first or last time that someone had written a similar program as one of their beginner programming projects. (I know I have written all kinds of silly stuff in MS-DOS batch, in MS Access VBA, and in MultiMedia Builder of all things.) It's the marketing it as an actual encryption program -- and not bothering to take it down five years later when you know better -- that turns it into a problem.

Comment: They say the software is "99% Hacker Proof Technology". You are now officially among the top 1% of hackers. :)

Comment: To be fair, the author of this encryption technology *does* mention that it's an "Alpah" version. I'm sure these issues will all be addressed in the "Bata" version.

Comment: @maxathousand they call it a Bata version as soon as it's bata than nothing. Looks like there's still a long way to go.

Comment: It must've been made by [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55832456/windows-shell-add-item-to-protected-folder-2559a1f2-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0) (I found it by Googling the method 1/3 GUID).

Comment: Also notice methods 1 and 3 do exactly the same thing.

Comment: @user253751 considering that the question has been asked this year, it's not the same guy.

Comment: Maybe it was [this one](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20880/Folder-protection-for-Windows-using-Csharp-and-con) then. Are they all copying the same GUID because they don't know how GUIDs work?

Comment: I would like to unsubscribe from this mailing list

Comment: Hilarious 'encryption'. @grawity If you mean you don't want to get notifications for replies to your answer by say email check the email for information or else SE information on it. If it's the notifications here that I don't know about. Oh and a paradox about the name in encryption software. Yes true but what if it's a well known cryptologist? Does that mean that by writing their own implementation it makes the encryption bad? :) (Sorry - I love philosophy. Your point is sound although it could be made even sounder I am sure.)

Comment: "Alpah". Legendary stuff.

Comment: @maxathousand Think it should be rather named Beat instead of Bata.